# The rotational symmetry groups of the $5$-cell and the icosahedron are isomorphic. Is there a geometric proof of this fact?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, symmetry, polyhedra, polytopes

The rotational symmetry group of the $n$-simplex (not permitting reflections) is always the alternating group $A_{n+1}$. When $n=4$, this coincides with the rotational symmetry group of the icosahedron and dodecahedron, which is also $A_5$.  (I believe this is the only "exceptional isomorphism" between symmetry groups of regular polytopes in any dimension, i.e. one besides the isomorphism between dual polytopes.)

Obviously one can prove this fact by showing that each group happens to be the alternating group on $5$ elements, but I am curious whether there is a geometric approach to exhibiting the isomorphism - some natural bijection between rotations of the $4$-simplex and rotations of the icosahedron which shows they exhibit the same multiplicative structure, without determining what that structure is.

Comment: Related: https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/six.html

Answer (score 2):

In the graphical diagram below, each face (including the exterior part of the graph, which is the face opposite the central triangle) is numbered 1,2,3,4, or 5 such that one face with each number meets at every vertex of the regular icosahedron.

[image]

With this labelling, the four faces numbered 1 are coplanar with the faces of a regular tetrahedron and would form this tetrahedron by stellation. The same is true of each of the other numbers.

The resulting five tetrahedra are rotations of each other about each of the fivefold axes of the icosahedron. Moreover, each pair of tetrahedra (such as the $\{1,2\}$ pair) meet at three of the thirty edges, so all pairs of tetrahedra have the same geometric relations with respect to each other. This guarantees that the five tetrahedra formed by this stellation process have the same symmetries with respect to each other as the tetrahedral faces of the pentachoron, thereby matching the icosahedral and pentachoral symmetries.